# When I swap between the fragments , the data in the previous fragment is disappearing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

this is my activity class

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

            username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
            password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

            DashbordFragment f = new DashbordFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("username",username);
            b.putString("password",password);
            f.setArguments(b);
```

creating a fragment and passing it using bundle into the fragment f

```
            DashbordFragment fragment = f;
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
```

changing of fragments on click of menu items

```
         public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Fragment fragment=null;
            if(id == R.id.nav_dashboard){
                 fragment = new DashbordFragment();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_inbox){
                fragment = new InboxFragment();
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction 
               fragmentTransaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

this is for replacing

```
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
               fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
             findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: that is because you are replacing fragments on container, so when every fragment transaction commits, new instance of fragment is created.

Comment: how to correct it ??

Comment: try to add fragment on container,in your onNavigationItemSelected() and don't forget to add background color to your parent view of  fragments, otherwise their views will overlap in some cases.

Comment: can u please explain me how as i m new to android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add or override the saveInstanceState on your FragmentClass? This is only if you wanted to rely on store state and it is recommended that you use instance variables

```
@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  // Save some state!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference in your application to store the username and password. By using it you can access the saved data throughout the application as and when you please.

This will give you a basic idea about the same: [Shared Preference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

To save the data:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
getActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("username", "abc"); 
editor.putString("password", "123"); 
editor.apply();
```

To retrieve the data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefKey, 
MODE_PRIVATE);
if (prefs.contains("username")&&(prefs.contains("password"))){
        String userName= prefs.getString("username",null);
        String usrPassword = prefs.getString("paswword",null);
        if((userName!=null) && (usrPassword!= null)) {
          //whatever you need to do with the obtained data
        }
    }
```

Comment: currently i m not storing anything Shared preferences , hre username and password are the data coming from backend , i have used username and password just to show some data in a fragment.

Comment: so why not get the data from back end in the fragment?

Comment: i am getting th data from backend bt the problem hre is... the data present in one fragment is disappearing if i swap or click on the other fragment

Comment: so u mean t o tel...to get the data directly into the fragment from the back end ?? i herd tht v cnt directly get th data frm th backend into th fragment

Comment: well you can. One can call a service in a fragment and get the data.

Comment: Call your service in this fragment and get the data. I use retrofit to call a service.  You might be using something else right ,use that.